# Exception with ScalaZ OptionT

Tags: scala, future, scalaz

Consider the following code which uses ScalaZ's `OptionT`:

```
val answer = for {
      customer <- optionT(function1(codeString))
      customerId <- someOptionT(Future(Seq(function2(customer)))
      alerts <- someOptionT(Future.sequence(function3(customerId))
} yield alerts
```

- `function1` returns `Future[Option[Customer]]`
- `function2` returns `String`
- `function3` returns `Seq[Future[Option[String]]]`

Meanwhile this is `someOptionT`

```
def someOptionT[T](t: Future[T]): OptionT[Future, T] = optionT[Future](t.map(Some.apply))
```

I get the following exception on the last line of the `for` comprehension (with `alerts`):

```
could not find implicit value for parameter F: scalaz.Functor[scala.concurrent.Future]
```

Any idea as to why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error message is totally unclear, but the problem is exactly the same as if you wrote `myFuture.map(whatever)` in the REPL without an implicit execution context in scope.

```
scala> import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.Future

scala> def foo(myFuture: Future[Int]) = myFuture.map(_ + 1)
<console>:8: error: Cannot find an implicit ExecutionContext. You might pass
an (implicit ec: ExecutionContext) parameter to your method
or import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global.
       def foo(myFuture: Future[Int]) = myFuture.map(_ + 1)
                                                    ^
```

Scalaz provides a `Functor` (and a `Monad`, etc.) for `Future`, but you have to have an execution context around to get them. Import `global` (or provide one some other way) and you'll be fine.

Comment: I tried `global` and Play's execution context as well, but neither worked. Strange.

Comment: What are your Scalaz imports? If you're not going kitchen-sink you need at least `scalaz.std.scalaFuture._`.

Comment: Yes, I just noticed the same thing as I saw your response. Thanks for your help.